# Como fazer com que o textarea aumente de altura automaticamente até um certo limite?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor maneira de fazer com que o `textarea` aumente de altura automaticamente até o limite de `500px` quando o usuário entrar com conteúdo.

> Não utilize outra biblioteca além do `Jquery`.

**CSS:**

```
textearea{
    resize: none; /* impede que o próprio usuário altere o tamanho do textarea */
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: tem um plugin jquery q faz isso

Comment: @user3230262 E qual é o plugin? Já vi que a resposta é longe de ser trivial, então referências externas ajudariam bastante...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sempre que o `textarea` for editado, por qualquer meio (teclado, mouse, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, etc), verifique se seu tamanho na tela é menor que o tamanho do seu conteúdo real (i.e. o conteúdo que está sendo servido pela barra de rolagem) e, enquanto for, aumente o tamanho do elemento.

```
$("textarea").bind("input", function(e) {
    while( $(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight +
                                   parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) +
                                   parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"))
           && $(this).height() < 500 // Altura máxima
    ) {
        $(this).height($(this).height()+1);
    };
});
```

<sub>Fonte: [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10080841/520779).</sub>

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXM5z/2/). Notas:

- Se você atribuir **programaticamente** o conteúdo do `textarea`, deverá invocar o código acima manualmente (pois o `input` não faz isso pra você);
- O código acima *talvez* possa ser melhorado para evitar esse loop que incrementa de um por um, mas como a resposta original fazia assim (e estou sem tempo pra testar as alternativas) preferi deixar como estava.

  - O uso de [`outerHeight`](https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) em vez de simplesmente [`height`](https://api.jquery.com/height/) é para levar em conta o `padding` (e opcionalmente também a `margin`) em vez de se considerar somente a altura do conteúdo. Talvez por isso o incremento de um em um, já que caso contrário o cálculo seria mais complexo (e na prática, não reparei nenhum problema na performance percebida).
- Minha resposta alternativa (no histórico de edição) não funciona em todos os casos, por diversos motivos. Minhas tentativas de calcular o tamanho do conteúdo por outros meios (ex.: usando um elemento auxiliar) também não tiveram sucesso, de modo que essa foi a solução mais completa e simples que achei.

Comment: Gostei da sua solução pelo detalhe que evita a barra de rolagem aparecer enquanto o tamanho do textarea não atingir o 500px, por isso irei atribuir como melhor resposta, apesar de não funcionar no IE. Ainda estou estudando ambos os códigos para realizar melhorias, obrigado pela colaboração.

Answer (score 5):

Aqui fica outra ideia:

```
$('#texto').on('keyup onpaste', function () {
    var alturaScroll = this.scrollHeight;
    var alturaCaixa = $(this).height();

    if (alturaScroll > (alturaCaixa + 10)) {
        if (alturaScroll > 500) return;
        $(this).css('height', alturaScroll);
    }
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/d9mdQ/1/)

Este código corre cada vez que uma letra é inserida (quando a tecla é solta) ou quando texto é copiado para o textarea com o evento `onpaste`.

Quando a tecla é levantada o código lê a altura do Scroll e da caixa. Se o scroll fôr maior então faz a caixa aumentar até ao limite de 500.

Como o @mgibsonbr referiu o evento `input` tem vantagens sobre o `keyup`, talvez boa ideia usar os três. O `input` tem a desvantagem de [não ser aceite nalguns browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input). O IE sendo um deles.

Comment: A vantagem do `input` sobre `keyup` (em teoria, pelo menos) é que se você segurar uma tecla e não soltar mais, o `textarea` vai sendo preenchido mas a altura não aumenta. E se ela passar de `500` enquanto se está fazendo isso, ela não aumenta mais - fica com a que estava naquele momento.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, boa sugestão! Juntei essa ideia à resposta, obrigado e referí que o IE (para não fugir à tradição) nao lida bem com o `input`.

Comment: Não sei se você e o @mgibsonbr classificam como reparo técnico (gambiarra) isso, mas eu usaria uma aproximação das mais simples possíveis, e um timer para fallback (levíssimo, de 3 segundos pra cima).

Comment: @Bacco Acho que depende dos seus objetivos. Eu gostei do código da minha resposta porque é bastante preciso e não dá nenhum glitch visual. Mas com certeza muita gente ficaria hororrizada ao ver um loop que incrementa de um em um...

Comment: @mgibsonbr agora vocês precisam inventar um que diminua se o texto for cortado :)

Answer (score 1):

Fiz uma pequena alteração para ele voltar ao tamanho padrão se a pessoa desistir de escrever e apagar o que tinha escrito deixando o textarea vazio.
No meu caso a altura é de 40px.

```
$('textarea[name="responder"]').on('keyup change onpaste', function () {
    var alturaScroll = this.scrollHeight;
    var alturaCaixa = $(this).height();

    if (alturaScroll > (alturaCaixa + 10)) {
        if (alturaScroll > 500) return;
        $(this).css('height', alturaScroll);
    }

    if( $(this).val() == '' ){
        // retonando ao height padrão de 40px
        $(this).css('height', '40px');
    }
});
```

Infelizmente não consegui fazer ele diminuir gradativamente quando a pessoa vai deletando letra por letra, mas no meu caso já foi o suficiente.
Espero que isso possa ajudar mais alguém e obrigado pela ajuda que me deram com este código.

Answer (score 0):

//Dei uma alterada para pegar automaticamente todos os *textboxes* do formulário e fazer o *resizer*.

```
function ResizeTextArea(){ 
    for (var j=1; j < form.length-1; j++){
        if (form[j].type=="textarea"){

            txtBox = form[j];
            nCols = txtBox.cols;
            sVal = txtBox.value;
            nVal = sVal.length;

            nRowCnt = 1;

            for (i=0;i<nVal;i++){ 
                if ((sVal.charAt(i).charCodeAt(0) == 13) || (sVal.charAt(i).charCodeAt(0) == 10)){ 
                    nRowCnt = nRowCnt +1;
                } 
            }

            if (nRowCnt < (nVal / nCols)) {
                nRowCnt = 2 + (nVal / nCols); 
            }
            if (nVal == 0){
                nRowCnt = 1; 
            }
            txtBox.rows = nRowCnt;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solução completa com altura mínima e máxima e resolvendo problemas com scroll:

```
var textarea =
{
    tornarFlex:
        function (id_textarea, altura_minima, altura_maxima)
        {
            var textarea = document.getElementById(id_textarea);
            if (typeof altura_minima == 'undefined')
            {
                altura_minima = textarea.offsetHeight;
            }
            if (typeof altura_maxima == 'undefined')
            {
                altura_maxima = 0;
            }
            textarea.style.height = altura_minima + 'px';
            textarea.addEventListener('keyup', new Function("textarea.ajusta('" + id_textarea + "'," + altura_minima + ", " + altura_maxima + ");"));
        },
    ajusta:
        function(id_textarea, altura_minima, altura_maxima)
        {
            var textarea = document.getElementById(id_textarea);
            while 
            (
                textarea.offsetHeight < textarea.scrollHeight 
                && (!altura_maxima || textarea.offsetHeight < altura_maxima)
            )
            {
                textarea.style.height = (textarea.offsetHeight + 1) + 'px';
            };
            if (textarea.offsetHeight < altura_maxima)
            {
                textarea.style.overflowX = 'hidden';
                textarea.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
            }
            else
            {
                textarea.style.overflowX = 'visible';
                textarea.style.overflowY = 'visible';
            }
        }
};
```

textarea.tornarFlex(id_elemento, 20, 100);